# CiviCRM dashboard and menus do not load

Tags: wordpress, civicrm-home, debugging

I cannot load CiviCRM 4.6.3 in my WordPress installation. I can login to Wordpress, but when I click on CiviCRM,

1. The menu is not loaded
2. the dashboard remains on "Loading…"

When I check the console (F12 in Firefox) I see this error:

> L’utilizzo di getAttributeNode() è deprecato. Al suo posto utilizzare getAttribute(). mootools.js:343:0
>       SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' admin.php:1:0
>       SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' admin.php:1:0

What can I check?

[image: Screenshot of CiviCRM failing to load after WordPress login]

Comment: There is not enough information here to help.  Please edit your question to provide some more information.  For instance: When did it last work?  Have you made any changes (upgrades, new Wordpress plugins, moved server) since this started happening?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but you haven't specified whether this is a new installation or something that happened after an upgrade or other change to an existing installation.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a javascript error on your Wordpress site. These are typically caused by buggy WP plugins. I suggest you disable plugins to identify the problem.

Here are more detailed [javascript troubleshooting steps for CiviCRM](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850).

Answer (score 1):

I resolved by deleting the contents of the table "civicrm_menu"

Answer (score 1):

You may need to rebuild the menus, you can do this by going to http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/menu/rebuild&reset=1

This should rebuild the menus and bring them back.  It's easier than truncating the db table.